# Services are not responding in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, axon

So both services are running and command service is reaching the axon server. But when I send post to my command service I'm not able to reach it out.

Actually, if I send

```
 POST http://localhost:8081/bowl
```

I expect to get

yes, you have a bowl, etc...

here is my axon server's yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: axonserver
  labels:
    app: axonserver
spec:
  serviceName: axonserver
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: axonserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: axonserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: axonserver
        image: axoniq/axonserver
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: grpc
          containerPort: 8124
          protocol: TCP
        - name: gui
          containerPort: 8024
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            port: 8024
            path: /actuator/health
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        env:
        - name: AXONSERVER_HOSTNAME
          value: axonserver
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: axonserver-gui
  labels:
    app: axonserver-gui
spec:
  ports:
  - name: gui
    port: 8024
    targetPort: 8024
  selector:
    app: axonserver
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: axonserver
  labels:
    app: axonserver
spec:
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 8124
    targetPort: 8124
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: axonserver
```

And this my command service yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: command-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: axonserver
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: axonserver
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: command-svc
          image: celcin/command-svc
          env:
          - name: AXONSERVER_HOSTNAME
            value: axonserver
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: command-service
  labels:
    app: axonserver
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8081
  selector:
    app: axonserver
    tier: backend
```

I am a bit confused in the Kubernetes world. Which point of config file should be changed then

Here also how they are looks like

```
   NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
axonserver        ClusterIP      None             <none>        8124/TCP         25m   app=axonserver
axonserver-gui    LoadBalancer   10.103.181.173   <pending>     8024:31755/TCP   25m   app=axonserver
command-service   NodePort       10.109.18.71     <none>        8081:30515/TCP   23m   app=axonserver,tier=backend
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          33m   <none>
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: Error is like : Could not get any response

Comment: how is `POST http://localhost:30515/bowl` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Not responding, bcz command service serving on 8081. connection refused

Comment: as I saw : `command-service` is `NodePort`  why its `LoadBalancer`?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVani i thought i has to do this way, i replaced with nodePort but didnot changed result. i will remove it

Answer (score 2):

with `NodePort` or `ClusterIP`, you can access to the `pods` using :

`curl -k -v http://10.109.18.71:8081/bowl`

or `POST http://10.109.18.71:8081/bowl`

for `POST http://localhost:8081/bowl`,

you have to build up `kube proxy` or use `ingress` for connection from outside.

Comment: im using minikube, for dev purpose. Do you have hin how to build up proxy

Comment: Additionally i have to access services not pod. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Nodeport normally allocates a port in the range between 30000-32767. Check the Nodeport service to see if it is really serving on 8081.

```
kubectl get svc command-service -o yaml
```

Comment: command service is serving on 8081. With docker it works fine. but k8s assigning nodePort with that range. when i list them, they looks as i listed above @Seeron